# onCaptureProgressed vs onCaptureCompleted, Camera2 in Android

Tags: android, android-camera2

Can anyone please tell me what is the difference in the two callbacks.
I couldn't find any good resource on internet.

What is the meaning of "partial result"?

Answer (score 0):

The developer documentation is pretty lengthy on the details for [onCaptureProgressed](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback.html#onCaptureProgressed(android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession,%20android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest,%20android.hardware.camera2.CaptureResult)).

But basically, some of the capture result metadata Keys can be available sooner than others, so onCaptureProgressed is a way to receive those Keys as soon as possible.

Those early Keys often include the state of focus, auto-exposure, and auto-whitebalance, which are important to receive as early as possible, when taking flash photos or similar.

But because camera implementations vary a great deal, exactly what keys are included in each partial result is not specified, so you have to check each partial (and then the final TotalCaptureResult) until you find the keys you need for your particular application.